# A quote about a barrel organ. In a fantasy novel 30 or more years old

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book at least three decades ago, in a paperback edition, rather fat. It might be much older than that. I **know** it was a Fantasy novel, but indeed this quote is not specially related to the Fantasy aspect.

I remember vividly one scene, of really no importance to the plot, because I found it funny. Two characters talk about a third one who is a street musician (none of the three a main protagonist). One says casually that the third one was somewhere "playing with his organ" (in fact, a simple barrel organ). The second one asks "With what ?" and the first one repeats "His organ". And what is funny at this point is the reaction of the second one who clearly misunderstood the perfectly innocent intended meaning of the word "organ" in this context. I remember having found the exchange hilarious, especially considering the fact that none of the three was a particularly delicate person. All three were drifters, beggars, petty (or maybe not so petty) thieves, maybe even worse criminals, I forgot the details.

To connect this scene to the Fantasy : I remember that the three characters belonged to a group, or a gang, the **leader of which had some magical powers.**  But I don't think any of these three had magical powers themselves.

Comment: Being a drifter or a beggar should not necessarily be equated with being a criminal.

Comment: @Lexible No, but the people I rembered were i na gang. I just did not remember whoe they were and how severe into crime their involvment.

Comment: @Otis Yes, I had forgotten the title, the first time, while vaguely remembering the main line. But I did not remember the connection with the "organ". Now I realise it was the same story, after all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would guess you are thinking of an exchange in [The Anubis Gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Anubis_Gates) by Tim Powers. As you say it is between some anonymous gang members not main characters:

> “What’s a pandemonium?” whispered one of the men in the rear.
>
> “It’s like a calliope,” answered a companion. “I heard one played at the Harmony Fair last summer, when I went there to see my sister’s boy play his organ.”
>
> “His what?”
>
> “His organ.”
>
> “Lord. People pay money to see things like that?”

Comment: Yes ! Exactly! And when I just read the last line of your answer, I laughed as much as the first time I read it ! Kudos !

Comment: What is the context just before? "Pandemonium" was probably **not** meant as a musical instrument, was it ?

Comment: [Relevant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1XWo4ufMkG4) (cc @Alfred)

Comment: @Randal'Thor You are right, it might well have been a small portable **real** organ and not a barrel organ. I vaguely  remembered a beggar playing a barrel organ, but with the context John Rennie provideded, Harmony fair, a calliope and (probably) a harmonium rather than a "pandemonium", this kind of small organ does make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Alfred Doctor Romanelli has just led his gang to kidnap Doyle and it turns into a massive fight (though they do manage to knock Doyle unconscious and kidnap him). Romanelli complains: *“You’ve caused such a pandemonium that I’ll have to set a radiating disorientation spell to confuse the pursuit you’ve certainly roused.”* Hence the comment from one of the gang members *“What’s a pandemonium?”*

Comment: @JohnRennie Thank you ! I do remember the main story of "Anubis Gates" but I have forgotten most of details after do many decades. This particular exchange stayed vivid but I had forgotten the relationship with my other memories if the book.